# StaticContentInterceptor | Static resource xpm.js not found

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, sdl-tridion, sites-9.1, jsp

While running(start) the server in Eclipse, I see below Error being logged in console. While it is able to locate one of the `xpm.js`, it is unable to locate the 2nd `xpm.js` as highlighted in **RED** below.

[image]

So far as checked in whole eclipse solution, I have only one below code in one jsp file:

```
<xpm:if-enabled>
    <script src="${markup.versionedContent('/assets/scripts/xpm.js')}"></script>
</xpm:if-enabled>
```

I think, the above `<xpm:if-enabled />` corresponds to the below console line, which is working & fine

```
INFO  c.n.d.service.MBDispatcherServlet-
***Request URL:http://localhost:8071/en/system/v2.2/assets/scripts/xpm.js
```

Can you please let me know what is causing the below error/warning and how to fix it ?

```
WARN  c.s.w.c.i.i.StaticContentInterceptor - Static resource not found in 
static content provider for /en/system/assets/scripts/xpm.js. Fallback to webapp content
```

Please refer the first console image for a stack trace

Comment: Can you share the version of dxa-java you are using , did you upgrade the dxa-java recently

Comment: No upgrade recently. DXA version is 2.2.3

Comment: I don't think this is a matter of being able to locate `xpm.js` on the first request, but not on the second request.  In general, all Static Item requests are logged at INFO level, but handling the `xpm.js` request results in a WARNing that such item in not stored as a Binary in the CD Data Store and it falls back to reading it from disk directly ("fallback to webapp content").  Admittedly, it seems that WARNing level is unnecessarily alarming.